# How can I check the temperature of my CPU in Windows?

Tags: windows, cpu, temperature

Does Windows provide a means to check my CPU temperature natively?

If not, are there any software tools which can reveal this information?

Comment: I'm sure somebody's going to vote to close this as a duplicate, but while I found a bunch of questions asking what software to use I didn't actually find any specifically asking "Can Windows do this on its own?" which I think is novel enough to a potential searcher to keep.

Comment: PowerShell can access WMI info that includes temp if the manufacturer exposes it (and you run  PowerShell as Administrator). I have a script on my blog to do so: http://ammonsonline.com/is-it-hot-in-here-or-is-it-just-my-cpu/ or just the script itself as GitHub Gist: https://gist.github.com/jeffa00/9577816. Good if you want something you can script yourself rather than downloading an app.

Comment: Similar question (with answer) on stackoverflow.com: [Get CPU temperature in CMD/POWER Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738494/get-cpu-temperature-in-cmd-power-shell)

Comment: You can get it with WMI : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736193/how-can-we-get-a-cpu-temperature-through-wmi

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Actually this information is given to OS by the BIOS, but you will need an application to expose the information. You can find a lot of applications to do this:

1. [Realtemp.](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/)
2. [CPU thermomether.](http://www.cputhermometer.com/)
3. [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/)

Comment: CoreTemp is nice, but beware of InstallIQ crap (installs toolbars/ads in browser) when downloading CoreTemp, use the standalone version.

Comment: As of May 2016: To download the Core Temp standalone, click "More downloads". Only then will the link become visible.

Comment: I would like to add "NZXT Cam Software" also in the list as it gives in depth analysis of temperature and doesn't have to install ad on for this https://www.nzxt.com/camapp found from https://developingdaily.com/article/how-to/how-to-monitor-cpu-temperature-in-windows-10/128

Comment: CPU thermomether with virus! according to virtustotal.com

Comment: Realtemp with virus too (virustotal.com) :P

Comment: _Not_ recommended: [AMD System Monitor](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-100). Unsigned installer and executable, install is a mess, and displays only core frequencies. No temperatures.

Answer (score 86):

Windows doesn't expose this information out of the box - you need to install any of a myriad of tools to find it.  (For something lightweight, I like [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/).)

Comment: Open Hardware Monitor is open source software. It has gui but is able to create a log as well.

Comment: Remember to run Open Hardware Monitor as an administrator. Running it as a normal user you could end up with missing temperature info, especially for the CPU.

Comment: [Libre Hardware Monitor](https://github.com/LibreHardwareMonitor/LibreHardwareMonitor) is an Active fork of OpenHardwareMonitor

Answer (score 49):

There is no built-in Windows utility to do this, so you need to use another tool.

My personal favorite is [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php). SpeedFan can monitor CPU temperatures, GPU temperatures, S.M.A.R.T. data, hard disk drive temperatures, and more; and if you want to you can also adjust fan speeds with it too.

[image: Screenshot of Speedfan]

Comment: SpeedFan is very powerful, but it's very clunky IMO.  I don't like it even for serious technical use.  The interface is just so awful!

Comment: sadly the download site now doesn't actually give you the program but a load of malware/adware/crap/junk instead.

Comment: @jwenting: Don't click on the large green button that says "Start Download", but scroll down to the Download section and click on the direct link to the executable... eg. "The latest version is [**SpeedFan 4.49**](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php)"

Comment: It crashed my Win 8 OS immediatelly

Comment: Says my 5820k is at 127C ... Seems legit.

Answer (score 47):

You might want to take a look at [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html), which shows a wide variety of system sensors.

In addition to temperature, it also shows system voltages, fan speeds, and power consumption - not only for your CPU, but all the hardware connected to your computer that has sensors (including your graphics cards and hard drives).

For a more "advanced" tool (showing much more information), you may want to use [HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com/).

Comment: This one is the most decent one in this thread

Comment: @LeaHayes Could you please indicate which one is the right download link please? I don't see any way to discriminate the non-adware one...

Comment: @Martec it seems like they have changed their webpage; if I remember correctly; there was one of those dodgy adverts with a big green "Download" button. I think the purple download links are probably fine; just run it through your virus checker before using. I hope that this helps.

Comment: They are all purple buttons. You guys are not mistaking HWMonitor with Open Hardware Monitor, are you? -Did you removed the comment because of not being sure that it actually had both bloated and clean versions?

Answer (score 8):

*** First note that I have only used *NVIDIA System Monitor* and have no user-knowledge of other tool software for this purpose.

If your PC has an Nvidia graphics card, or installed monitor software, their System Monitor tool is available at nvidia.com. IT IS AMAZING!!!

Add the program to your desktop and you can open the program and instantly know CPU, GPU, and hard disk drive temperatures, as well as memory % in-use, vital multi-core CPU % in-use for each, net data transfer speed and identifies CPU clocking speeds and more.

It also shows fan speeds and allows you to change their settings from auto to manual control easily (I use this feature as a temperature spike preventive on hot Summer days).

I physically clean the inside of my pc more often since I used this program to record a 30° CPU average temperature drop after a good cleaning.

Comment: CPU temp monitoring is supported only for quite limited number of Nvidia chipsets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_System_Tools And it's already bundled with drivers

Answer (score 5):

I'm really surprised that [MSI Afterburner](https://www.msi.com/page/afterburner) has not been mentioned. Downloads from the offical MSI website and is the most trustworthy I can see in the list above. It's a really great tool and does lots of monitoring, not only GPU but CPU and other temperatures as well. Nice system tray icons.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no native Windows 7 method to monitor temperature; a third-party utility is required.
Coverage of all temperature sensors (CPU, graphics, motherboard, and hard disk drive) woule be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Windows does not provide the necessary tools for monitoring your CPU temperature.

For third-party applications I recommend [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/). It displays the current, minimum and maximum temperature for every core. It also includes an "always on top" mode or it can display the current temperature from your system tray.

Comment: Yep, it works. And as per 2013-10-09, it is also digitally signed, so it gives some confidence about this third-party tool.

Comment: Using Core Temp seems risky: https://www.reddit.com/r/Rainmeter/comments/2xoc0j/coretemp_now_comes_bundled_with_malware/

Answer (score 3):

- [System Information Viewer](http://rh-software.com/) can check the temperature of each CPU core along with the temperature of other devices that report their values such as memory controller hub, HDD, SSD, GPU, UPS, etc. SIV is designed for Windows 10, 8.1, 8.0, 7, Vista, XP, 2016, 2012, 2008, 2003, 2000 and NT4. Windows 95, 98 and Me are also supported. Most processors that can run Windows are also supported including AMD, Intel, Itanium, DEC Alpha, VIA. Enormous menu has search function to locate which system information value you want to inspect. Rated 4.2/5 on [Softpedia](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/System-Information-Viewer.shtml).

  [image: SIV Menu]
- [MooO System Monitor](https://www.moo0.com/?top=https://www.moo0.com/software/SystemMonitor/) lets you choose by checkbox what to display allowing you to create a desktop widget that can sit off to the side. Was a Softpedia [Editor's Choice](https://www.softpedia.com/reviews/windows/Moo0-SystemMonitor-Review-161088.shtml) when it was reviewed long ago, it's on its 64th update (2019/6/15) now. Most recent review (on [Chip.de](https://www.chip.de/downloads/Moo0-SystemMonitor_33699862.html), in German) rates it 4.2/5 last year. Runs on Windows XP/Vista/7/8.1/10 in 45 languages. Skinable and supports up to 8K monitors.

  [image: MooO System Monitor]
- [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) (by Piriform/CCleaner) Something simpler from somewhere you've heard of, provides basic information in an easy to use traditional styled GUI. Online help file and [Menu Find](https://support.piriform.com/hc/en-us/articles/204044304-Finding-information-in-Speccy?mobile_site=false) feature to locate the menu you need. There are free and paid versions (and no ADs, just that free version has no support). This is the same company that created [Defraggler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defraggler), arguably the ***best*** disk defragmenter (by far).

  [image: Speccy Screenshot]
- [SIW](https://www.gtopala.com/siw/tools.php), along with a temperature display, offers a number of other functions such as displaying passwords hidden behind asterisks, NAC changer, Network Tools, Monitor tester, Browser cookie and history explorer, along access to Windows tools and settings. Available in free ([Community Supported](https://chocolatey.org/packages/siw)) and [paid versions](https://www.gtopala.com/buy/buy-other.php). Has a [GitHub](https://github.com/gtopala) for viewer utilities.

  [image: SIW Temperature Screen]

Answer (score 2):

I use [BatteryCare](http://batterycare.net/en/download.html).

It shows the CPU as well as hard disk drive temperature with a simple UI.
It has some really awesome features if you are using it on a laptop.
To clear some myths about batteries, please read [this article](http://batterycare.net/en/guide.html).

I have also installed SpeedFan, but rarely do I use it. It is pretty complicated to use plus risky if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: This software install adware. Be careful!