# Why does my laptop keep shutting down?

Tags: shutdown, gaming

Why do my laptop shut down when I play SimCity 4. Maybe it's getting to warm, but why? I use Windows7. When I feel under it it feels very hot. Why does it get so hot? I let it stand on a wooden desk.

Comment: It's you, who has to tell us if it's getting hot. If it is, it will shutdown to prevent damage. On what surface does your laptop stand when you play? You can try cleaning your cooling fan and see if that helps.

Comment: I can highly recommend cleaning out the fans and applying new thermal paste. I recently acquired an older laptop that regularly ran into the high 80s under moderate load. Cleaning it  out and new paste reduced the temperature dramatically. I also went out and bought a cheap cooling pad for R180 (around $18) and with visual studio running full pelt or playing dota 2, my temperature rarely goes above 45-50 degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your laptop's processor, there is a predefined temperature threshold. When the temperature is exceeded, the laptop will be forced into shutdown to prevent further damage to the hardware.

[Install a temperature monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/395434/how-can-i-check-the-temperature-of-my-cpu-in-windows) and note down the idling and active temperatures. Like @Ashtray mentioned in the comments, your fan may be dirty, or you can try reapplying thermal paste on the CPU if you can access it.