# Testing laptop hardware

Tags: laptop, cpu, dell-latitude

I  purchased an untested Dell Latitude off ebay and only have 14 days to return if the hardware goes faulty. What are the best tools I can use to test the hardware out. I'm going to keep it running for a week just to be sure.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic on Superuser.

Comment: Just get UBCD and use those tools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) covers SMART, CPU and other sensors for temperature. If the laptop is sick, it will run hot, and other similar tools are discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/395434/how-can-i-check-the-temperature-of-my-cpu-in-windows).  Once your SMART/temp tool of choice is installed, flog your system hard with a trial copy of [O&O Defrag](http://www.oo-software.com/en/products/oodefrag) then run [FurMark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) for a while for GPU testing.