# Asus K53SJ upgrade to 8Gb of Ram ussually getting screen glitch

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, upgrade

I've just upgrade my ASUS K53SJ to 8Gb of RAM (the original is 4Gb), I'm using 2x Elpida 4Gb 1333Mhz.

When I use just single one of RAM, everything works fine, but when I combine and use both of my RAMs, my computer usually freeze like this pic below

[image: screen glitch after few hours using]

And for sure, I can't use it any more, I need to hold the power button to shut it down.

I'm using Windows 8.1 with lastest update, running on Intel SSD 530 120Gb.

Please any1, do you have any idea what happens with my laptop? :(

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Processor: Intel® Core™ i5 2410M

Chipset: Intel® HM65 Express Chipset

Graphic: NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 520M with 1GB DDR3 VRAM

Storage: Intel SSD 530 120Gb + WD 500Gb

Bios: last version

---

**UPDATE 2**

I did try to get another DDR3 8Gb instead of 2x4Gb, and seems like everything is running ok until now, so I will close my question here.

The problem may come from the voltage, my new Samsung DDR3L 8Gb (1.35v) seems working perfect with my laptop, it is running very smooth and no conflict.

Thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound hi, I've just updated

Comment: If I were to hazard to guess the problem is the memory itself.  If you use one stick of the original memory and one stick of the new memory does this happen?

Comment: Download any bootable live linux distro which features `memtest` to test your memory. Either BIOS is applying timing which breaks one of the modules or maybe the power distribution / voltage is not good enough for both modules. How long does it take until it freezes? Maybe something is overheated when both modules are used.

Comment: @Ramhound I did try to use my original RAM and the one I bought separately, all is running smooth and ok :(

Comment: @Marki555 I have the same feeling like you, not sure how to check all the temperature right before my laptop freezes, do you have any tool that can do that?

Comment: Ussualy, it will long for 1 or 2 hours until it freezes

Comment: Check this question https://superuser.com/q/395434/150695